# Why is it rare to use the %pre rpm script?

Tags: service, upgrade, rpm

In [maximum rpm](http://rpm5.org/docs/max-rpm.html#s2-rpm-inside-erase-time-scripts) under the section on the %pre install script, it mentions that it's rare to use the %pre script. In fact, it further states that (at that time anyway) none of the 400+ RedHat packages used the %pre script.

I would think the %pre script would be the ideal location to stop the existing service before installing files over top of the currently installed version.

Is my thinking wrong? How is it that RedHat got away with never using %pre during upgrade for this purpose in any of their service packages?

Answer (score 3):

Yes %pre is much more commonly used than when "Maximum RPM" was written in 1997. That doesn't change the fact that %pre should be used "rarely".

The reason is that %pre prevents installation (and may cause an entire
transaction to fail if there are needed install time dependencies).

Stopping a service in %pre and restarting in %post opens a larger window
where the service is not running than simply restarting a service in %post

The already running service typically reads its configuration files
only on startup (and so rpm can replace files while daemon is running).

And running executables have a reference count on the file system and so
continue to run even if the file that was executed was removed/replaced
by a newer package.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went and did the research I should have done before asking this question. I downloaded several service packages from RedHat 7.1 and ran:

```
rpm -qp --scripts <package-name>.rpm
```

I found out 1) that it's no longer true that %pre is not used. Even among the few that I checked a couple of them used %pre, and 2) it appears that most services just allow rpm to overwrite their data files and binaries during upgrade, and then use the upgrade portion of the %postun (post uninstall) script to restart (or try-restart) the service.

I would have thought this rather unsafe, as while you're writing over data files (especially) during upgrade, the old running service might get confused. It seems to me ultimately it's safer to stop the service during upgrade on %pre and start it again on upgrade during %postun... but that's just me.